# Durrett Exercise 4.6.4

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Let $X_n$ be r.v.'s taking values in $[0, \infty)$. Let $D = \{ X_n = 0 \ \text{for some}\ n \geq 1 \}$ and assume
>   $$P(D \vert X_1, \dots, X_n ) \geq \delta(x) > 0 \quad \text{a.s. on}\ \{X_n \leq x \}.$$
>   Use Lévy's 0-1 law to conclude that $P(D \cup \{\lim_n X_n = \infty \} ) = 1$.

Let $C=\{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n\}$.
For this question, I tried to apply the theorem suggested, and I have that $E(1_D|F_N) \rightarrow 1_D$, which is the same as $P(D|X_1,...,X_n)\rightarrow 1_D$. To show $P(C \cup D)$, I'm thinking about showing that $D \subset C^c$. But I'm not show how am I supposed to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $\{ \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n \leq M \}$ we have $X_n \leq M + 1$ i.o. so

$$P(D \vert X_1, \dots, X_n) \geq \delta (M + 1) > 0 \quad \text{i.o.}$$

Since the right hand side $\longrightarrow 1_D$, we must have

$$D \supset \{ \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n \leq M \}.$$

Letting $M \longrightarrow \infty$ implies $D \supset \{ \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_n < \infty \}$ a.s.

Comment: thank you! Just wondering for this question if we're we supposed to show that the limit exists? Do we also have to consider the limsup?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, for the Levy 0-1 law part, is it enough just to say "let $F_1= \sigma(X_1), ..., F_n= \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$. Then we have that $F_n \rightarrow F_{\infty}$. Since $D \in F_n$, $D \in F_{\infty}$. Hence, we can use the 0-1 law"?

Comment: Yes, this is a good explanation. I omitted this from my answer, but if you want to explain all details, you of course have to include this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything makes sense now!

Comment: You‘re welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry.. one more question. I just realized that we ended up showing $P(D^c \cup {lim X_n = \infty}
)=1$, not $P(D \cup {lim X_n = \infty} )=1$.. Was I supposed to show $D \subset C $ originally instead?

Comment: We have $D \cup D^c \subset D \cup \{\liminf X_n = \infty \}$, hence $P(D \cup \{\liminf X_n = \infty\}) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much!